# What is the AEGIS design rationale for one way rounds and slow diffusion?

Tags: block-cipher, algorithm-design, authenticated-encryption, one-way-function, permutation

The [AEGIS reference document](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round3/aegisv11.pdf) doesn't specify why the authors chose a slow diffusion process and a one way round transformation.

[image: aegis round]

As you can see the previous state is XORed with AES applied to itself shifted by one (wrapped around). This is not a permutation.

The diffusion is also slow when comparing to the possibilities that the AES 4x4 byte matrix allows. See for example [Haraka v2 hash](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/098.pdf):

[image: haraka round]

Above are two permutation variants @ 256 bits and 512 bits respectively.

This is done with columns, if you shuffle bytes you can go up to a 2048 bit state with amazing diffusion potential (16 AES ops, 1 byte taken from each for the next round).

AEGIS instead goes for much slower diffusion.

Comment: Looks like type-3 Feistel. Probably used to maximize what can be executed in parallel. Inverse is not needed so it can (must?) be one-way. Related to diffusion paper states: "In AEGIS, the first difference in the state would pass through at least 4 AES round functions before being affected by another difference. In addition, when a difference passes through AES round functions, the differences are injected into at least four elements in the state, so it becomes more difficult to eliminate the state difference."

Comment: Feistel networks are permutations. They are invertible. Permutations are used inside primitives to preserve entropy, when using one way functions multiple rounds in a row you can have internal collisions and it's difficult to reason about them. Here is a type 3 feistel: https://media.springernature.com/lw685/springer-static/image/chp%3A10.1007%2F978-3-030-44223-1_25/MediaObjects/496968_1_En_25_Fig3_HTML.png

Comment: Yes, it has additional F operation that makes it non-inverable. Probably internal collisions are not significant due to big block size. It is very specific design. If you don't get good answer you can also try to ask authors.

Comment: Also note there is no "permutation" word in the paper. They mention stream cipher.